# Given two strings, find if 5 characters or more of the first string is a section of the second and vice versa (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Example input:
str1 = 'ZZZABCDEFRFR'
str2 = 'DDDDDDDDDDDDABCDERR'
Example output: True
```

```
Example input:
str1 = 'DDDDDDDDDDDDABACDERR'
str2 = 'ZZZABCDEFRFR'
Example output: False
```

I tried something similar to this but it skips characters until it finds one matching. This is not what I want...

```
def issubsequence(s1, s2):
 
    n,m = len(s1),len(s2)
    i,j = 0,0
    while (i < n and j < m):
        if (s1[i] == s2[j]):
            i += 1
        j += 1
     
    # If i reaches end of s1,that mean we found all
    # characters of s1 in s2,
    # so s1 is subsequence of s2, else not
    return i == n
```

Comment: Contiguous (ie, substring) or discontiguous?

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop to iterate through your first string. Then use the `in` operator to check if it is a substring in the second. The code below checks if str1 is in str2. You can swap them to check the other way.

```
for i in range(len(str1) - 4):
    substr1 = str1[i:i+5]
    if substr1 in str2:
        print(f'{substr1} in {str2}')
```

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26608/3279700986.py in <module>
----> 1 complement2('AATTCC','TTAAGG')

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26608/1594489491.py in complement2(sequence1, sequence2)
      1 def complement2(sequence1,sequence2):
      2     for i in range(len(sequence1) - 5):
----> 3         substr1 = str[i:i+5]
      4         if complement(substr1) in sequence2[i] or reverese_complement(substr1) in sequence2:
      5             return True

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try again William, I had a type, I had str instead of str1 in line 2.

Comment: it does not scan through the 1st string though. I am trying to do the first example but it gives me false instead of true

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) intersection on slices to the two strings:

```
def f(s1,s2,len_=5):
    if min(map(len, [s1,s2]))<len_: return False

    return bool({s1[i:i+len_] for i in range(0,len(s1)-len_+1)} & 
                {s2[i:i+len_] for i in range(0,len(s2)-len_+1)})
```

Test it:

```
cases=[(True,'ZZZABCDEFRFR','DDDDDDDDDDDDABCDERR'), 
        (False,'DDDDDDDDDDDDABACDERR','ZZZABCDEFRFR'),
        (True,'abcde','abcde'),
        (True,'xabcde','yabcde')]

for b,x,y in cases:
    print(b,x,y,f(x,y))
```

Prints:

```
True ZZZABCDEFRFR DDDDDDDDDDDDABCDERR True
False DDDDDDDDDDDDABACDERR ZZZABCDEFRFR False
True abcde abcde True
True xabcde yabcde True
```

Alternatively, use `next` with a generator with same substring slices:

```
def f2(s1,s2,len_=5):
    if min(map(len, [s1,s2]))<len_: return False
    return next((True for i in range(0,len(s1)-len_+1) 
                   if s1[i:i+len_] in s2), False)
```